# Winforms - How to allow user to increase font size of listview with hidden controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am creating an winform application that will run on a tablet PC.  One form for this app will have a listview control.

I would like to allow the user to change the font size based on preference (ie did they remember their glasses today).  A few ways that I can think of would be a numeric-up-down or +/- button controls.  Both of these ways require screen real estate that is very limited.

Is there a control or technique that would allow font size changes with a hidden-when-not-used control?

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on suggestion from [@GenericTeaType](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44269/generictypetea):

At the class level:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
```

On the listview control:

```
private void lst1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //start stopwatch
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
    }

private void lst1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //stop stopwatch
        sw.Stop();
        //how long did stopwatch run for
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;
        //show font change form if time exceeds 3 seconds
            if (elapsedTime.Seconds >= 3)
            {
                //show form - pass in current listview font size
                frmFontSizeChange ffsc = new frmFontSizeChange(slv.ReleaseFontSize);
                ffsc.ShowDialog();

                //refresh schedule with new font size
                populate_lst1();                    
            }
       }
```

Comment: As a comment and an aside, this is about 1000x easier with WPF... I know that's not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just show/hide a control for a certain period of time on the form MouseClick event.

For example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
}

Timer Timer1;

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Will need handling to ensure it's not already displaying, etc... then:
    FontSizeControl.Show();
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void FontSizeControl_FontSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Change the font size
    ...

    // Reset the timer
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    Timer1.Enabled = true;

}

void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontSizeControl.Hide();
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

What this would basically do is to show the FontSize changing control that you've made (or will make) when the user taps the screen. If they then don't touch the control it'll change when the `Timer` ticks. Or, it will go away after the user has stopped tapping the +/- for x amount of milliseconds.

**UPDATE** for showing after 3 seconds.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer2_Tick);
    Timer2.Interval = 3000;
}

Timer Timer2;

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Timer2.Enabled = true;
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Timer2.Enabled = false;
}

void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontSizeControl.Show();
    Timer2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Is there way of running the timer as the mouse click is held down?  Ie the user holds the mouse click down for 3 seconds and then the font-size change box appears?

Comment: Or, an improvement on this would be to self contain the auto show/hide logic within the control itself and not from the Form.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just add a hidden control, but if you're not going to show it I don't think there's much point. Just handle the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` event in the form and/or listview and if it's + or - make it bigger or smaller.

Or possibly it would be safer to use some thing like `Ctrl` + `+` rather than just `+`.

Comment: The keypress events would work but the tablet has no keyboard so I prefer not to have the user open a on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word tablet from your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for a Tablet PC, but would a [`FontDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.aspx) not do the job? It is hidden when not used, and you might even instantiate it on a Button click, so ne resources are taken to make it live, etc.

Comment: Great idea @Will but probably will result in too much control (ie they select wingdings with 100pt font...)